# Ruby on Rails : "required: true" Don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have already fixed it

Closed

[![enter image description here][1]][1]    <%= text_field_tag(:first_name, @user['first_name'], class: "user-input", required: true) %>

I have 2 forms

In form 1, I'm trying to make required some fields but it is not working.

when i input any text ,it don't show the popup as the above image

In form 2, it is working

Comment: Please update your question with the form 1 and form 2

Comment: Hi @Pavan 
in form 1, when i input any text it won't show the popup as the above image.

Comment: the both form are the same code

Comment: You need to show us the code for both form1 and form2 to understand how they are structured. It help us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not only the `text_field_tag` is important but also its enclosing form. For example, validation could fail if the tag is not enclosed in a `<form>` tag or if the form has a `novalidate` attribute. Show your code, please.

Comment: BTW, if you are rendering a model related form, you should use `form_for` and `text_field`, e.g. `<%= form_for @user do |f| %>` and `<%= f.text_field :first_name %>`. See [Binding a Form to an Object](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object)

Answer (score 3):

It's best to deal with things like this in the model. In your app/models/user.rb file, add:

```
validates_presence_of :first_name
```

This will mean updating the record without a first_name present will cause the save to fail. You then need to render the edit page again, which should show the user the relevant error messages.

Comment: It is always good to have model validations, but this doesn't answer the question *why `required :true` didn't worked?*